# Is there a web based converter between rwx and the octal version?

Tags: permissions, chmod

I can never remember what the conversion is from something like `rw-r--r--` to `644`. Is there a simple web based converter between the 2?

Comment: It's just an octal number with the binary digits being mapped to rwxrwxrwx (user, group, other).

Comment: this can easilly be calculated by hand. or they can be displayed by `stat -c` ...

Comment: Does your `chmod` not support the symbolic mode. I have been told that most do. The Gnu one defiantly dose. e.g. turn on group write `chmod g+w`, set the mode `rw-r--r--` `chmod =r,u+w` or `chmod u=rw,go=r`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This site provides an interactive way to see what permissions bits are set when various bits are set/unset.

- http://permissions-calculator.org/

The "calculator" looks like this:

[image: ss#1]

Comment: The link is broken now, which is why we generally discourage link-only answers, but it's hard to criticize when the question asked for a link

Answer (score 14):

Why do you need an octal number in the first place?

I always use:

```
chmod o+x file   # all + eXecute permissions
chmod g-w file   # group - write perms
chmod u=r file   # user can just read
chmod ug=rw file # user,group = read and write
chmod a+w file   # user,group,others + write
```

ugo(a) is easy to remember. However, you can confuse o:=owner? o:=other? But what would be u, if o=owner? u:=user, therefore o=other.

Some commands like numerical permissions only. Okay, it's not hard to calculate, if you remember the two sequences: ugo + rwx.

```
    r   w   x  | Sum
u   4   2   1  | 7
g   4   -   1  |  5
o   4   2   -  |   6
---------------------
                 756
```

Yes, very artificial.

When it comes to s and S I have to consult the manual. Maybe google next time. :)

Comment: Other programs that can have permissions don't always provide support for the semantic strings since the underlying interface is octal and easier to support. The first part of this answer is condescending and unnecessary. Just answer the question...

Comment: If you read my answer as condescending you're misinterpreting the tone.

Comment: > Why do you need an octal number in the first place?

Comment: > "Some commands like numerical permissions only." I may add: Some documentation only lists numerical values.

Answer (score 11):

Octal is used for permissions because it's an *easy* conversion.  Each group of `rwx` forms one octal digit.  All you have to remember is the first 3 powers of 2:  4, 2, 1.  `r` = 4, `w` = 2, `x` = 1.

`rw-r--r--` = `110 100 100` = `4+2+0 4+0+0 4+0+0` = `644`

Answer (score 9):

I like this permissions calculator:
http://file-permissions.ninja

Comment: Normally, I would flag this for being a link-only answer, but since the OP was explicitly asking for a website, I will let it pass. Be aware though that link-only answers are often discouraged.

Comment: This site doesn't seem to work right now. I see "403" errors in the console.

Comment: +1 for a calculator that calculates permissions to/from the "ls" format (i.e. -rwx--S---)

Comment: This is the only answer that directly answers the question

Answer (score 5):

I have this little alias that you can put in your .bashrc (or equivalent).

DISCLAIMER: I am not the author of the script, and I'm not sure who wrote it... but props to him/her for doing this.

```
alias lsp="ls -l --color | 
      awk '{k=0; for(i=0;i<=8;i++) k+=((substr(\$1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/)*2^(8-i));
      if (k) printf(\" %0o \",k); print}'"
```

Comment: Many thanks for that, @nico - here is the same code converted as a perl one-liner, and used in bash: `echo 'rwxrwxrw-' |  perl -ne 'BEGIN{sub conv{ chomp(my $ins=shift); my $k=0; for(my $i=0;$i<=8;$i++) { my $tmps = ( substr($ins, $i, 1) =~ /[rwx]/ ); $k+= ( $tmps*(2**(8-$i)) ); }; if ($k) { sprintf(" %0o ", $k); } else { "??" ; }; }; }  print(conv($_)."\n");'` would print "`776`". Cheers!

Comment: Sadly the scripts above are incomplete and do not handle setuid/setgid/sticky permissions.

Answer (score 4):

This is by far the most convenient, and is besides I believe, exactly what you asked for originally:

http://ss64.com/osx/chmod.html

It is fully interactive, though you cannot edit the string "-r-x-------" but you can the octal or the checkboxes. Doing either updates the other.

[image: My favourite tool for just this]

From the same page:

**Numeric (absolute) mode:**

From one to four octal digits
Any omitted digits are assumed to be leading zeros.

The first digit = selects attributes for the set user ID (4) and set group ID (2) and save text image (1)
The second digit = permissions for the user who owns the file: read (4), write (2), and execute (1)
The third digit = permissions for other users in the file's group: read (4), write (2), and execute (1)
The fourth digit = permissions for other users NOT in the file's group: read (4), write (2), and execute (1)

The octal (0-7) value is calculated by adding up the values for each digit
User (rwx) = 4+2+1 = 7
Group(rx) = 4+1 = 5
World (rx) = 4+1 = 5
chmod mode = 0755

Comment: This "calculator" is broken with respect to 4-digit numbers even though the text talks about 4-digits.  i.e. Entering 2777 should show "-rwxrwsrwx", but "--w-rwxrwx" is shown instead.

Comment: there is a fith digit, the mac/dac level

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is not a "web" calculator, since [nico](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3860/nico)'s answer does not handle setuid, setgid, and sticky indicators, but does get up-votes, an example of an updated scriptlet that handles the extra permissions states may be warranted:

```
ls -l | \
awk '{k=0; for(i=0; i<=8; i++) k+=((substr($1, i+2, 1) ~ /[rwxs]/)*2^(8-i));
     if ($1 ~ /^.{3}[Ss]/) k+=2048; if($1 ~ /^.{6}[Ss]/) k+=1024;
     if ($1 ~ /[Tt]/) k+=512; if(k) printf("%4o ",k); print; }'
```

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246202/is-there-a-shell-script-converter-between-rwx-rwt-etc-and-the-octal-version) is a better fit for scripted solutions where [glenn jackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3860/nico) offers a `perl` `stat` one-liner similar to:

```
$ what="/tmp"
$ perl -s -e '@fields = stat "$f"; printf "%04o\n", $fields[2] & 07777' -- -f="$what"
1777
```

The awk script is based on one found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246202/is-there-a-shell-script-converter-between-rwx-rwt-etc-and-the-octal-version)

Comment: That's great, I will definitely update my .bashrc now! :)