# Is there a shell script converter between rwx/rwt etc and the octal version?

Tags: shell, shell-script

I gone through the script

```
echo 'rwxrwxrw-' | perl -ne 'BEGIN{sub conv{ chomp(my $ins=shift); my $k=0; for(my $i=0;$i<=8;$i++) { my $tmps = ( substr($ins, $i, 1) =~ /[rwx]/ ); $k+= ( $tmps*(2**(8-$i)) ); }; if ($k) { sprintf(" %0o ", $k); } else { "??" ; }; }; } print(conv($_)."\n");'
```

It's really wonderful but its missing extra permissions like sticky bit, suid, sgid. I will me more appreciated, if you could include them in the script.

Answer (score 0):

this is bash:

```
perms="rwxr-xr-x"
p=0
for ((i=0; i<${#perms}; i++)); do
    ((p <<= 1))
    [[ ${perms:i:1} == "-" ]] || ((p += 1))
done
printf "%o\n" $p   # ==> 755
```

Does not handle sticky bits, etc. For that, use `stat`

```
$ touch afile
$ chmod 2700 afile
$ ls -l afile
-rwx--S--- 1 jackman jackman 0 Nov 29 09:36 afile*
$ stat -c '%a' afile
2700
```

Perl has a builtin [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) function:

```
$ perl -e '@fields = stat "afile"; printf "%04o\n", $fields[2] & 07777'
2700
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of `stat` is not necessary for handling sticky, setuid, or setgid (even if it is more unwieldy), and BASHisms are unnecessary.  An example for /tmp works on a very old UNIX without BASH:

```
ls -ld /tmp | \
tee /dev/stderr | \
awk '{ k=0; for(i=0; i<=8; i++) k+=((substr($1, i+2, 1) ~ /[rwxs]/)*2^(8-i));
       if ($1 ~ /^.{3}[Ss]/) k+=2048; if($1 ~ /^.{6}[Ss]/) k+=1024;
       if ($1 ~ /[Tt]/) k+=512; if(k) printf("%04o\n",k) }'
drwxrwxrwt   3 sys      sys         2560 Jul 16 12:39 /tmp
1776
```

That said, [glenn jackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman)'s `perl` `stat` solution is preferred for conciseness, and with a minor rework, allows accepting the target from a shell variable (and also works on the same ancient UNIX):

```
$ what="/tmp"
$ perl -s -e '@fields = stat "$f"; printf "%04o\n", $fields[2] & 07777' -- -f="$what"
1777
```

The awk script is based on one found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9518/22653)